# Deletion of objects in Django with foreign key in it

Tags: django, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

This question might be a stupid one, but I need to validate it from the SO community.

I have 2 models.

```
class Address(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, null=True)


class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Now If I want to delete one instance of Address, will it delete the instance of Area object it is pointing to as a Foreign key?

```
address = Address.objects.filter(...).delete()
```

PS: I know the on_delete functionality in Django.It is required when a foreign key object is deleted and to prevent those objects pointing to this foreign key, this parameter is used. In my case, scenario is reverse.

Answer (score 1):

No, It will not delete `Area` row, because its a foreignkey field.
So on deleting Address instance, corresponding `area` instance will not be deleted, unless you override `delete` method of the model to delete the instance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common doubt for one who starts to learn the database operations.

As you have mentioned there is on_delete in django which is different.

First we should understand what a **Foreign key** is. It is another table in which a set of data is stored. Say we have an entry for **address1** with area as **area1**. Similarly I create an address **address2** with same area **area1**. Now if the deletion of **address1** deletes **area1** also then the relation concept of the other instance is not attained. That is in general Foreign key just defines a new model in the database. You will have to remove the FK instance by overriding the default method. Else it wont delete the FK instance.

Answer (score 1):

The `Area` will not be affected. However, if you deleted the `Area`, the `Address` will be deleted (as the default `on_delete` behaviour is cascade).